# How to implement Django Form using Minimal jQuery Ajax [ Level of question - Intermediate ]

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, integration

If you were to replace the code marked [from here - till here] with something minimalistic what would it be?

```
$('#post_form').submit(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            var data = {}

            // From here
           data.k = $('#k').val(); //'k' would be the id of some input field
            data.j = $('#j').val(); //and so on for 'l', 'm' , 'n' etc. you get it
            .......
            // Till here

            $.post("/ajax/post_test/", 
                data, 
                function(responseData) {
                  // handle the response
                },
                "json"

            );
        });
```

It would be awesome if this 'data' object could be directly used in Django as a form and hence be able to leverage Django's inbuilt validation system.

The ideal answer would look something like this -

```
data = $('#post_form').DumpData()
```

And if anybody feeling really kind today could you also please tell me how i can handle the response as well? I would be really really grateful. Thank you guys.

P.S. Save my soul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method:

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements.

So it doesn't give you an object, but it works as the data parameter for a jQuery AJAX call.

If you really want them as an object, there's [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), which isn't exactly there as it is an array of objects with names and values, but you could then turn it into a one-level object.

Comment: Ahh and i fall in love with jQuery all over again. :]. Thanks buddy.

Comment: What thoughts about returning ajax  validations through the django view?